# Mono for Android debugging in VS2010

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, debugging, xamarin.android

I'm trying to use Mono for Android; so far so good.
But debugging in VS2010 it's very, very slow. Step by step debugging it's even more slow! 
Is something wrong with my installation, or this is the case for Mono for Android ?
Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

Using the debugger in the current release of Mono for Android is indeed very slow. It's an issue that I know is high on the team's priority list, but in the meantime it's pretty rough. I would suggest running your app without the debugger when possible, and then [make use of logging](http://android.xamarin.com/Documentation/Guides/Android_Debug_Log) in order to see what's going on when you need to.

Comment: Thanks Greg.Besides debugging, Mono Android apps runs as smooth as Java native apps ? I'm asking because on the emulator it seems it runs pretty slow, even without the debugger attached. Maybe this is the case with all Android apps on emulator ?

Comment: Yes, the emulator is painfully slow for everything, including Java. Just see all the results for: http://www.google.com/search?q=android+emulator+slow

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this may be addressed in the latest release: http://android.xamarin.com/Releases/Mono_for_Android_1/Release_1.0.3

"Improved Debugger Performance: both stepping over your .NET code and examining variables is significantly faster. We eliminated some major bottlenecks caused by roundtrips from Visual Studio to the device and this has resulted in faster debugging and faster exploration of your variables."